# I can't login to heroku via Git on Windows 7

Tags: git, heroku

I installed Heroku toolbelt on my 64-bit Windows 7.

When I run `heroku login`, it prompts me to type in my email. I do, then press Enter.

But then, I get this message:

```
Login is currently incompatible with git bash/cygwin
In the meantime, login via cmd.exe
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli/issues/84
```

The URL goes to a Github issue of people discussing the issue, but without a solution.

How can I login to Heroku using the Toolbelt on Windows 7?

Comment: This error message seems pretty self-explanatory.  Heroku login is not supported under Cygwin.  Have you tried logging in from a command prompt?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ah, I see. I didn't open open cmd.exe directly. But now I'm confused. Was there an update between summer and now that causes this message? I think I remember being able to login via Git bash on Windows...

Comment: Yes, and in fact I am currently using BitBucket from Git Bash.  Maybe you need to upgrade?  How long ago did you install that bash?  In the meantime maybe the Windows command prompt can be a workaround for you.

Comment: I installed the latest Git for Windows, then Heroku Toolbelt. I customized the install so I get the Toolbelt without its version of Git. Before that, I just installed Heroku Toolbelt with its Git. But I still got this same problem. For now, I'll login thru `cmd` as a workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a linux-like environment, use the git-bash.exe packaged with the [latest git-for-windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

You should be able to login from that bash shell mingw2-based session.

Answer (score 1):

Login with windows cmd prompt. After that create your app or other part in git bash.

Answer (score 0):

use windows cmd.exe and run it as administrator

Answer (score 0):

On version 6.13.1, running using `cmd.exe` did not work for me.  However, the terse message in [this comment](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/84#issuecomment-310155899) helped.  It suggested running `winpty heroku login`, which required that I install cygwin, mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++, gcc-g++ (6.3, not 5.x), make, then clone [the winpty repo](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty), and build and install that.